# FileReader API issue in Safari V6.0

Tags: javascript, safari, filereader

I am using the following code snippet to read a file in javascript:

```
if(window.FileReader && filelist.length > 0) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = reader.onloadend=function(event){
        self._ogrUpload(self, event);
    };
    reader.readAsText(filelist[i]);
    console.log(filelist[i]);
}
```

This works a treat in Chrome but not in Safari V6.0.

In Safari the upload appears to work but the function `_orgUpload()` is not called. So I replaced this with:

```
reader.onload = function(event) { alert("TEST");};
```

This did not work either. Does FileReader actually work in Safari 6.0? As I cannot see any errors thrown in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see what kind of functions are supported

```
function checkFileApi(){
    var debuggers="<h4>browser supports following</h4>"
    if (window.File) debuggers+="Supports File api<br>"
    if (window.FileReader) debuggers+="Supports FileReader api<br>"
    if(window.FileList) debuggers+="Supports FileList api<br>"
    if(window.Blob) debuggers+="Supports Blob api<br>"

    console.log(debuggers)
}

checkFileApi()
```